# Change SQL query on Auth, Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

When logging in, the query fails, because "email" is not on "usuario", it's in "persona"

```sql
Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `usuario` where `email` = admin@localhost limit 1)
```

It's not a solution to change the database model, as not all "persona" are "usuario", but all "usuario" are "persona".

Tried to set the relationships:

```php
class Persona extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{....}
public function usuario()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Usuario');
}
//----------------------------------------------------//
class Usuario extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                AuthorizableContract,
                                CanResetPasswordContract
{
{....}
public function persona()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Persona');
}
```

Both tables have the same key.

But the query doesn't change, I though maybe Laravel could make an "INNER JOIN" somewhere, don't know if Laravel can do that automatically, so I tried to change the query but don't know exactly where is located.

I thought in a solution like this, but it looks too easy, don't know if would be a good way =/

---

- Get EMAIL and PASSWD from post
- Get the ID, EMAIL and PASSWD from the BD with the SQL
- If [EMAIL and PASSWD match] Auth::loginUsingId(ID); [ELSE] Return with the errors.

---

As far as I know, the Auth::loginUsingId(ID); acts like a successful Auth::attempt()... but with this solution I'll need to know how to implement later Throttles and the "remember" option separately... all thoughts are welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: changed postLogin() but inside AuthController, so I can preserve the Throttles and Remember features, and the core still unchanged, here's the code if I can help others:

```php
//------------------------------------
// Auth\AuthController.php
//------------------------------------

protected function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    //Here's the custom SQL, so you can retrieve a "user" and "pass" from anywhere in the DB
    $usuario = \DB::select('
            SELECT
                persona.nombre,
                usuario.password
            FROM
                persona
            INNER JOIN
                usuario ON persona.id_persona = usuario.id_persona
            WHERE
                persona.email = ?
            LIMIT 1', array($credentials['email']));

    // Instead of:
    // if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    if ($usuario && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $usuario[0]->password)) {
        Auth::loginUsingId($usuario[0]->id_persona, $request->has('remember'));

        // Put any custom data you need for the user/session
        Session::put('nombre', $usuario[0]->nombre);

        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```